# Are there other powers which follow the rule $a^b = b^a$ than $2^4$?

Tags: exponentiation

I was trying to find these powers, but to my disappointment I only found $2^4 = 4^2$. **Edit:** $a$ must be different to $b$ of course.

Is that the only possible setting, and why? If we assume the number and the power can have also decimal values.

Comment: a=b will work forever

Comment: You mean other than a = b?

Comment: @Aryabhata, my math is a bit rusty, does that explain the x and y must be integers in order that to work? I am looking for decimal solutions too.

Comment: @mathnewbie: The answers generalize them...